# What is the difference between using bash and sh to run a script?

Tags: bash, shell

Does bash and sh execute a script differently? I executed a shell script with both bash and sh, and got the same output. So what is the difference?

Also, when you just run `./executable`, does it use bash or sh?

Comment: @Pandya The `$SHELL` variable is not used to decide what shell will interpret the `./executable` script. It doesn't necessarily tell what the current shell is either.

Comment: @jlliagre oh! ok. [wiki.debian.org](https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables) says "SHELL = The current shell."

Comment: @Pandya it actually should say "The user's login shell". The current shell might be different.

Comment: For another example, you can consider [my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1524254/910769), where `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash` led to the usage of a wrong version of `printf` causing `printf: %q: invalid directive`.  [M.T](https://superuser.com/users/755894/m-t) pointed me to [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26069697/4575793), thanks for that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That depends on the system you are running. One many OSes, especially Linux based ones, `sh` is a link to `bash`.

In such case, there are still some differences in behavior where `bash` try to be more like traditional bourne shell when called `sh`, but it still accepts most bashisms.

On some other OSes, like Debian based ones, `sh` is provided by `dash`, not `bash`. That makes a much bigger difference as `dash` doesn't support bashisms, being designed to be a clean POSIX shell implementation.

On proprietary OSes, `sh` is often either provided by a POSIX compliant `ksh88` which like `dash`, doesn't implement bashisms. On Solaris 10 and older, depending on what your PATH is, `sh` will likely be a legacy Bourne shell, predating POSIX.

In any case, you likely got the same output with your test simply because your script was not using any `bash` specific command, option or syntax.

When you run `./executable`, what shell will be run essentially depends on the shebang written at the beginning of the .executable script. That will be `bash` if the shebang specifies it:

```
#!/bin/bash
....
```

If there is no shebang and you call the script from a POSIX compliant shell, the script should technically be executed by the first `sh` found in the PATH. Many shell interpreters like `bash`, `dash` and `ksh` are considering themselves to be POSIX so will interpret the script. Note that the `SHELL` environment variable is not used here.

Comment: I looked around in `/bin` and I found that `sh` is a symbolic link to `dash` rather than `bash`. So how did they run the same? It wasn't really running any bash script commands, just terminal commands to use other packages' tools.

Comment: If your shell script is just sequentially calling other commands, any shell interpreter will run it with the same result. Nothing unexpected here.

Comment: This isn't related to the question, but what exactly is the difference between `bash` and `dash`?

Comment: Both are using the Bourne shell syntax. As I wrote in my reply, `dash` is a clean implementation of the POSIX shell standard. On the other hand, `bash` is a shell with quite a large number of extensions and non standard features, some inspired by `ksh`, `ksh93` and other shells, and some bash specific, known as bashisms. There is a tool named checkbashisms that helps identifying everything that is not strictly portable in a given shell script.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it could be, but it does not have to be. The two shells are not the same, but the basics are compatible. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash) for more details.

You can use the following line in a script to check the interpreter that is used:

```
ps h -p $$ -o args='' | cut -f1 -d' '
```

You can explicitly specify the shell that shall be used when the script is executed directly with the `sheebang` line:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
```