# what's the difference between bash my_script and source my_script

Tags: bash

Both of two lines below seems to execute my_script. What's the difference between the two processes?

```
$ bash my_script
$ source my_script
```

Comment: Also see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270966/what-is-the-difference-between-using-bash-and-sh-to-run-a-script

Answer (score 0):

A major different is that bash runs in a subprocess, while source is as if you are running the content:

```
$ cat my_script
echo $$
$ bash my_script
85183
$ source my_script
1581
$ echo $$
1581
```

Comment: So is the line `$ bash my_script` the same as simply calling the script name `$ my_script`?